# How to resolve Vue dependency cycle with axios api services and vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

To add a token to the axios requests, I want to access the token saved in Vuex's state in my Api base service:

**Api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '../store'

export default () => axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${store.state.token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

This Api base service is used by another service (FooService) to send specific requests to the backend:

**FooService.js**

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  fetchFoo() {
    return Api().get('foo')
  }
}
```

And inside Vuex's actions the FooService is called to fetch data and save them to the store.

**store/actions.js**

```
import FooService from '@/services/FooService'

export default {
  async fetchFoo({ commit }, queryParams) {
    const response = await FooService.fetchFoo(queryParams)
    commit('setFoo', response.data)
  }
}
```

**store/index.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import actions from '@/store/actions'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import mutations from '@/store/mutations'

export default createStore({
  actions,
  mutations,
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState()
  ],
  state: {
    foo: [],
    token: null,
    user: null,
    userIsLoggedIn: false
  },
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

Since adding the token to the axios headers, I get a dependency cycle error

```
2:1  error  Dependency cycle via @/store/actions:2=>@/services/FooService:1  import/no-cycle
```

and I cannot figure out how to resolve this. Is there a better way to get the token inside the base service?

Comment: Try adding token like this: ```'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.$store.state.token'```. You may need to add single quotes around ```'Accept'``` as well.

Comment: Thank you, but accessing the store via `this.$store` returns the error `this is undefined`.

Comment: How does your store/index.js look like?

Comment: I just added the store/index.js

Comment: You could include the store in main.js into your Vue instance. That way it will be accessible globally in components and mixins. Then you could change Api.js and FooService.js to mixins and include those into actions.js. As I mentioned, in mixins you can just access the store via this.$store and you don't need to include it, which causes the dependency cycle error.

Comment: I'm rather new to Vue mixins, but after a bit of research I don't really like the idea of transforming all of the services into mixins and merging them into another. It feels as if the concept of separating the services would fail. Especially since I use some of the services in .vue components and some in .js files, mainly the store actions. Apart from that I already have included the store in the main.js. Are mixins the only way to make the store globally accessible from there?